What is China's official policy in case a third country attacks Taiwan?
Taiwan, similar to the People's Republic of China, has territorial claims on islands in the South China Sea resulting in territorial disputes with regional countries such as Philippines and Vietnam.
There are frequent confrontations between Taiwan and Philippines regarding this dispute. In 2013, a Taiwanese fisherman was killed by Filipino coast guards resulting in a diplomatic rift between the two nations.
Let's consider a hypothetical scenario in which Taiwan is being attacked by any country other than China, let's say Philippines: what would China's reaction be in that scenario? Since China claims Taiwan as part of its own territory with the "One China" policy, would that mean that China would send its military to defend Taiwan from invasion? Is there any official policy in the PRC constitution regarding such a scenario?

I would assume their official policy is that they would defend Chinese territory (i.e. Taiwan) aggressively.  Why would they need to communicate anything on such a remote hypothetical?  Especially, especially, when their whole narrative is that there is only one China.

And after they have defended Taiwan they are going to use those troops to invade her.

@ItalianPhilosopher I would assume that China does not have official policies on things that are highly unlikely to ever happen.

@ohwilleke I was going to bet that some governments have policies regarding alien invasions, but wikipedia says otherwise. So I guess you're right.

I think a good place to start would be looking at the conflict it has with India. Here China do know that the de facto border is not the territory they claim. With this conflict China has been very diplomatic even though it considers India to occupy Chinese territory.
Another interesting place to look is the conflict with Russia where China would like some of the historical Chinese territory and where they through negotiation moved the border as late as 2008.
So if reality matches "official policy" then I think the answer will be that there will be diplomacy first no matter what.
